# Error-Implement interface in python 3.2 with the module overloading

Tags: python, interface, python-3.x

I am try to implement a interface in python with  the module "overloading" 
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3124/#interfaces-and-adaptation

The problem is that no found the module overloading when a try to run with python3.2

```py
 from overloading import abstract
 from overloading import Interface
```

```py
 ImportError: No module named overloading
```

how to fix my problem?.

Comment: AFAIK, there *is* no module `overloading` in standard Python; as the PEP notes, its status was "deferred".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PEP is a Python Enhancement Proposal. Not all PEPs are accepted. Due to some uncertainties about implementation, the author of **PEP 3124** [decided to defer the proposal](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008784.html). However, note that this was in **2007** with no progress since then, so I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for this one.

If you're after a mechanism for interface checking, you might be able to use the `abc` module in the standard library, which roughly covers the same interface & adaptation ground that **PEP 3124** proposed.

For a more full featured solution, I highly recommend [`zope.interface`](http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/). If you're put off by the zope namespace (you shouldn't be, it's totally independent) there are other lightweight interface solutions such as [`visage`](https://github.com/jwp/py-visage).

Comment: Thanks, I'm use zope.interface